# Mathematical Induction Factorials, sum r(r!) =(n+1)! -1

Tags: proof-writing, induction, factorial

How do I prove that $$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} r(r!) = (n+1)!-1$$

I was able to get to factor: $LHS = k(k!) + (k+1)(k+1)!$
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\, RHS = (k+2)! -1$

Comment: Have a look around the site --- I'm sure this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large\sum_{r = 1}^{n}r\pars{r!}}
=
\sum_{r = 1}^{n}\bracks{\pars{r + 1}\pars{r!} - r!}
=
\sum_{r = 1}^{n}\bracks{\pars{r + 1}! - r!}
$$
$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large\sum_{r = 1}^{n}r\pars{r!}}
=
\pars{2! - 1!} + \pars{3! - 2!} + \cdots + \bracks{\pars{n + 1}! - n!}
=
\pars{n + 1}! - 1! = \color{#0000ff}{\large\pars{n + 1}! - 1}
$$

Comment: Is this an improvement on the answers in the duplicate question that I pointed out? If so, that's where this answer belongs, so it's all together in one place.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I didn't know there was a previous answer before you mentioned it. I just checked that and I could see that one is based in the Induction Principle. Thanks for call that to my attention.

Comment: Did you read the comments before you posted your answer? My link to the older question was in the comments.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No. I didn't.